# Exchange 2013 Mailbox Role no Internet Access

Tags: exchange-2013

I'm trying to setup an Exchange 2013 environment with 2 VM servers in Hyper-V. 1 virtual server will be a mailbox role and 1 will be CAS.

Inside Hyper-v I have 2 virtual networks configured - 1 with internet access and one without. I was hoping to have the mailbox server not connected to the internet, and the CAS server would have 2 network connections.

Everything works fine for receiving emails, however I cannot send external emails as the DNS lookup fails. As soon as I connect the 2nd network connection to the Mailbox Server all emails in the queue are sent.

Is it possible to setup a mailbox server without internet access and have a send connector forward all emails to CAS to resolve dns, or do I need at least 1 mailbox server with internet access to have the send connector?

Update:
This is the error I get in the Queue Viewer (sensitive data replaced with "MailboxServerName" or "Domain"):

```
Identity: MailboxServerName\5088\5205500362771
Subject: RE: Test
Internet Message ID: <c92a820f95f247fcbace90e32edcf87e@mailboxServerName.internal.domain.com.au>
From Address: Greg@domain.com.au
Status: Ready
Size (KB): 10
Message Source Name: SMTP:Default MailboxServerName
Source IP: 192.168.0.105
SCL: -1
Date Received: 23/12/2014 11:19:01 AM
Expiration Time: 25/12/2014 11:19:01 AM
Last Error: 
Queue ID: MailboxServerName\5088
Recipients:  Recipient1@bigpond.com;2;2;[{LRT=};{LED=};{FQDN=};{IP=}];0;CN=Primary,CN=Connections,CN=Exchange Routing Group (DWBGZMFD01QNBJR),CN=Routing Groups,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=Domain,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=internal,DC=domain,DC=com,DC=au;0 Recipient2@bigpond.com;2;2;[{LRT=};{LED=};{FQDN=};{IP=}];0;CN=Primary,CN=Connections,CN=Exchange Routing Group (DWBGZMFD01QNBJR),CN=Routing Groups,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=Domain,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=internal,DC=domain,DC=com,DC=au;0
```

Comment: I have tried enabling "Proxy through Client Access Server" but that doesn't seem to fix the problem

Comment: What is the Mailbox Database server using for DNS?

Comment: There are two active directory servers, both of which have a connection to the internal network. One server also has a connection to the public IP.

Comment: So the Mailbox Database uses the DC/DNS servers? Do they have access to the internet? The Mailbox Database server and the CAS server should use the DC/DNS servers for DNS and the DC/DNS servers should have internet access to resolve external DNS lookups.